# How Can I Bulk Import Image Label By CSV

Tags: magento-1.9, import, image, csv, labels

I need to import image label of my images, how can i do it by csv,

[image]

Comment: Refer this http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3970/2443

Comment: @JaiminSutariya: From your above mentioned link, how can I handle duplicates of image label

Comment: That I am not sure but I think you can get it from $image object and can match for duplicates

Comment: okay, i have one more issue, how can i export my all products using custom script

Comment: You can export from System > Import/Export > Export and select products

Comment: my site consists 20k products, when i tried using System > Import/Export > Export, its return "No Valid Data Send Error". Is it possible 20k products export via System > Import/Export > Export