# Save product image labels programmatically magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-images, labels

I am saving the product programmatically using action class in magento 2 [[Reference link]](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/programmatically-update-image-labels/62501#62501).After saving the product i am saving the images.But while saving the labels of the images i am getting the following error...

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\DefaultBackend\Interceptor::updateImage()
```

I have used the following code for saving the image label after product save...

```
$_product = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId()); //$_product->getId() is 5 which is id of product saved 
            $attributes = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($_product);
            $gallery = $attributes['media_gallery'];
            //$gallery = $_product->getData('media_gallery');
            $images = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages();
            foreach ($images as $image) {
                $backend = $gallery->getBackend();
                $backend->updateImage($_product,$image->getFile(),array('label' => 'Blah'));
            }
```

Referred above code from this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/programmatically-update-image-labels/62501#62501) and made changes...

Please suggest how to use updateImage function in magento 2 and save labels for images after saving the product...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following way:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->product = $product;
    $this->registry = $registry;

}
```

Now

```
$this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
$product = $this->product->load(2);
$existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
    $entry->setLabel('BlahBlah-1');
}
$product->setStoreId(0);
$product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
//$this->productRepository->save($product);
$product->save();
```

Comment: The value is added in the 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value' table  but it is not showing as alt text of the product images in the admin panel

Comment: Load correct product, then It should change accordingly. May be you load store wise product, that's why it's create another entry for image into catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value table.

Comment: I have tried with new product save from front end..it saved with id no 6,but when i saw the product in admin panel after opening it is showing images but with no caption.

Comment: It is showing when i select default store view from the top while editing the product...when by natural flow directly clicking on product edit it is not showing while product opens for edit mode.

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: Tried..but still showing the in the default store view only not in the All stores view...

Answer (score 0):

On M2 2.3.3 I needed to use

```
    $this->storeManager->setCurrentStore(0);
```

and

```
    $product->setStoreId(0);
```

Only then could I save images with the hidden field set or the labels. My code was actually saving before but only to one of the stores. Needless to say I assumed Magento was broken and didn't check any of the store views.

To use storeManager you will be needing:

```
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

private $storeManager;

public function __construct(
    ...
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    ...
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```